# Adding multiple entities to one main form

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I am in the process of modifying forms to account for V9 of Dynamics which is being rolled out currently.

Our environment is using Dialogs but these are being deprecated with V9 which means we have to prepare the forms to be used instead of these Dialogs.

Due to how fragmented our solution is the data is all over the place in different entities and can all be written too at different times.

Is it possible to have multiple entities/records on the same form which are all editable? This way I can run rules to hide and show as people edit specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can identify, there is no "true" way to achieve this. However, if there are entities which are linked via a relationship within the solution, it is possible to add the "Party List" type field to the form and this will act as the link between the two entities. When you go to search for an existing record within the related entity, there is a new button which allows you too create a new record of that entity which directly associated with the form you were working on initially.

Comment: Add screenshots to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

We do have [editable subgrids](https://www.powerobjects.com/2017/01/30/dynamics-365-new-feature-editable-grids/). Add the subgrids of related entities & allow users to edit the related records in main record form at one shot.

[image]